# Spline of curve (python)

Tags: python, interpolation, spline

Given a sequence of points in a 2D plane, `[(x0,y0), (x1,y1), ...]`, I want to find a [spline curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) which passes through these points.

The classes in [`scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) for 1D spline requires increasing `x`, since the list of these `x`-coordinates is not necessary increasing (i.e. the curve is not a function, `f(x)=y`, but rather a parametrised curve). *Unfortunately, neither it is a function along `y` (otherwise by switching x and y coords the problem would be easily solved).*

I have tried with the Univariate interpolation classes but this is not having the desired effect. How can I use `scipy.interpolate` to calculate this spline curve?

Comment: I would recommend first try work out the maths of the problem. Once you have done that, then figure out how to implement it in your program.

Comment: The problem is very simple, I have a series of points in a 2D plane, I want to find a spline curve which passes through these points. My problem is that the list of the x-coordinates is not necessary increasing (i.e. the curve is not a function, mathematically speaking ). Unfortunately it is not even a function along y, otherwise by switching x and y coords the problem would be easily solved. The classes in scipy.interpolate for 1-d spline requires increasing x. I have tried with the Univariate interpolation classes but the result is not satisfactory. Someone has some suggestions?

Comment: Why is the result not satisfactory? Apparently, it works, but you have different expectations. What are your expectations, what are the current results? (pictures, hand-drawn sketch etc help.) My point is that sometimes, people have higher expectations than what can actually be achieved by straightforward math routines.

Comment: @Evert,   
simply it is not satisfactory because the Univariate interpolation classes seem to reorder the x in an increasing order and then they perform the interpolation, but as explained I do not want to reorder the x. The problem is clearly stated... yes it works but the classes find the function interpolating my points not the curve without reordering the x.

Comment: @Evert, people apparently do not carefully read the problems stated ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reconsider how you think about this problem: Actually `x` is the parameterisation of the curve (which one would usually denote `t` for time) and `y` is the `x,y` co-ordinate:

```
L = [(x0,y0), (x1,y1), ...]
X = numpy.array(L).T
# Equivalently (but less generally):
# X = [[P[0] for P in L], [ P[1] for P in L ]]

t,X = enumerate(L) # here t[0]==0 and X[0]==(x0,x1,..), X[1]==(y0,y1,..)
# or to name in a more confusing manner but match the docs: x,y = enumerate(L)
```

Then you can use various [`scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) functions, for example:

```
f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(t, X)
```

.

For example the straight line between `(0,0)` and `(1,1)`:

```
f = interp1d((0,1), numpy.array([[0,0],[1,1]]).T )
#          (t0,t1)  numpy.array([[x0,y0],[[x1,y1]]).T
#          (t0,t1)              [[x0,x1],[[y0,y1]]
f(0.5) # array([ 0.5,  0.5])
```

Comment: I don't want order them. For instance, the curve must pass before through (1,2), then through (2,2) and then through (1.5,3). If the x would be ordered the problem would be easily solved. The key point is that x are not increasing and must stay not increasing

Comment: no I don't know the parametrisation and the x are not at regular interval.

Comment: @user1234383 well, that's the best think you can use then :)

Comment: the idea is very nice but, given the error returned, I think that the second argument of InterpolatedUnivariateSpline must be a 1d array and not a 2d array as it is in the solution that you propose.

Comment: @user1234383 Let me know how this goes, it should now work...